# Following SOLID principles with android mvvm architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, solid-principles, android-mvvm

So, I have an app that has a login module which uses firebase to authenticate the user. Here is the LoginViewModel class:

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
var auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
var emailLiveData = MutableLiveData("")
var passwordLiveData = MutableLiveData("")
var resultLiveData = MutableLiveData<SignInResult>()
var showLoader = MutableLiveData(false)

fun createAccount() {
    showLoader.value = true
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailLiveData.value ?: "", passwordLiveData.value ?: "")
        .addOnCompleteListener() { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val result = task.result.user?.let {
                    SignInResult.Success(
                        it,
                        "Account created successfully. A verification link has been sent to your email."
                    )
                }
                    ?: SignInResult.Error(
                        "Authentication failed: ${task.exception?.message}",
                        "Something went wrong, please try again."
                    )
                resultLiveData.value = result
                sendVerificationEmail()
            } else {
                val result = SignInResult.Error(
                    task.exception?.message ?: "Unknown Error",
                    "Something went wrong, please try again."
                )
                resultLiveData.value = result
            }
            showLoader.value = false
        }
}

private fun sendVerificationEmail() {
    val user = auth.currentUser
    user?.let {
        it.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}

fun signIn() {
    showLoader.value = true
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLiveData.value ?: "", passwordLiveData.value ?: "")
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val result =
                    task.result.user?.let { SignInResult.Success(it, "Logged in successfully") }
                        ?: SignInResult.Error(
                            "Authentication failed: ${task.exception?.message}",
                            "Something went wrong, please try again."
                        )
                resultLiveData.value = result
            } else {
                val result = SignInResult.Error(
                    task.exception?.message ?: "Unknown Error",
                    "Something went wrong, please try again."
                )
                resultLiveData.value = result
            }
            showLoader.value = false
        }
}

sealed class SignInResult {
    data class Success(val user: FirebaseUser, val message: String) : SignInResult()
    data class Error(val exception: String, val message: String) : SignInResult()
}
```

}

Now if I initialise this view model class directly in my activity class, it will be a direct violation of Dependency Inversion principle. Suppose in future the client decides to use their own server for email and password sign in, then it will require changes in the activity as well. Is there a way to make sure my activity isn't directly dependent on the view model class? I am finding it hard to figure it out with viewmodel instance being required in my activity class to observe on some data changes like the `SignInResult` state.